# Reset value of an attribute to default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to know how I can set a models attribute and possible associations to its default value.

```
user = User.find_by(name: "Martin")
user.phone = 012345
user.save!
# some time later
user.phone = # set to default
user.save!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few options to set a default value of a column:

1. Set the default value in migration (preferable)
2. Set the default value in `before_*` callback

To **revert** to default column's value you can use [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaCache#`columns_hash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaCache.html#method-i-columns_hash):

```
user.phone = user.class.columns_hash['phone'].default
```

Comment: Ah you were quicker :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I want to revert the value of user, which has been changed before, back to its default value in a controller

Comment: @supersize see the edited answer, you can use `Model.columns_hash['column_name'].default`

Answer (score 1):

You already set default in the migration.

`:default => 'your_default`'

Comment: yeah but I mean if the value has already been set differently before

Comment: See @Andrey Deineko's answer

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use:

```
User.column_defaults["phone"]
```

instead of:

```
User.columns_hash['phone'].default
```

since `columns_hash` gets the raw default value defined at database level and skips defaults set in `ActiveModel`. See the following example:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: %i[open closed]
  attribute :deliver_at, default: -> { Date.tomorrow }
end

Order.columns_hash['status'].default # => "0" ('0' if default value was defined in the database or 'nil' otherwise)
Order.columns_hash['deliver_at'].default # => NoMethodError (undefined method `default' for nil:NilClass) if it's a virtual attribute or 'nil' if the column exists in the database 

Order.column_defaults['status'] # => "open"
Order.column_defaults['deliver_at'] # => Wed, 06 May 2020
```